# updating a variable value in global scope from inside the closure

Tags: php, laravel, closures

im trying to do some process on my database objects in parallel (`things`) , im using this package  to run things in parallel

https://github.com/spatie/async

i want to know how many of my things have been processed successfully so i defined `$stats` array in global scope and trying to update it from inside the

```
    $pool   = Pool::create();
    $things = Thing::all();

    $stats = [
        'total'   => count($things) ,
        'success' => [] ,
    ];

    foreach ($things as $thing) {

        $pool->add(function () use ($thing , $stats ) {

            // do stuff 
            return [$thing , $stats]  ;

        })->then(function ($output ) {

            // Handle success
            list( $thing  , $stats) = $output ;
            dump('SUCCESS');
            $stats['success'][$thing->id] = $thing->id ;


        }) ->catch(function ($exception){
            // Handle exception
            dump('[ERROR] -> ' . $exception->getMessage());
        });
    }

    $pool->wait();
    dump($stats);
```

even though i see SUCCESS in the output but when i dump my `$stats` at the end `success` is always empty

```
array:3 [▼
  "total" => 3
  "success" => []
]
```

i also tried to  pass `stats` to `then` by `use`  didnt make any difference

```
})->then(function ($output ) use ($stats)
```

when i dump `$stats` inside `then` i can see data working fine

```
    })->then(function ($output ) {

        // Handle success
        list( $thing  , $stats) = $output ;
        dump('SUCCESS');
        $stats['success'][$thing->id] = $thing->id ;
        
        dump( $stats);


    })
```

output from dump inside `then`

```
array:3 [▼
  "total" => 3
  "success" => array:1 [▼
    2 => 2
  ]
]
```

Comment: @Jeto thanx passing it by reference did the trick , pleas post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do several things:

Inherit `$stats` from the parent scope by reference, using the following on the first callback:

```
use ($thing, &$stats)
```

Then return that same variable as reference:

```
return [$thing, &$stats];
```

Finally, dereference the corresponding `$output` array by reference as well, in the next callback:

```
list($thing, &$stats) = $output;  // or [$thing, &$stats] = $output;
```

Note: this looks a tad sketchy and I'm not sure at all this is a proper way of using this library, but this should work at least.